# StreamReader.ReadLine is hanging when 2 clients are sending

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline

i was doing an experiment and i got one streamreader and 2 TcpClients streamreader keep on reading from the client 1 and never read from the client 2 until the client 1 send something
so if the client 1 never sent anything the streamreader will never read from the client 2

ive been trying for ages to fix it

```
       while(true) 
            {
             foreach (Client client in Clients)
                {
                    var sr = client.clientStreamReader;
                    string data;
                    try
                    {
                        if ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine(data);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                }
          }
```

(client is a class to make save the streamreader and write)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serve each client with a separate thread, try the following :

```
void ReadFromClient(Client client)
{
     var sr = client.clientStreamReader;
     string data;
     try
     {
       if ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(data);
       }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Then Loop over the clients, every time starting a new thread:

```
foreach (Client client in Clients)
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>  ReadFromClient(client)) );
}
```

Comment: one problem how im i gonna get the client since it is defined in the foreach loop but not in the thread